# Modifying namespace of all elements with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use the following XSLT to transform the content of an xml document. However, one of my elements is being copied with the previous namespace, not the desired one. See below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cd="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine.DataContracts" exclude-result-prefixes="cd">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="cd:ArrayOfMachine">
    <Inventory>
      <Schema>2018</Schema>
      <Machines>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </Machines>
    </Inventory>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMachine xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Machine>
    <Price>120000</Price>
    <Properties>
      <Axes>XYZ</Axes>
    </Properties>
  </Machine>
</ArrayOfMachine>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Schema>2018</Schema>
  <Machines>
    <Machine xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine">
      <Price>120000</Price>
      <Properties>
        <Axes>XYZ</Axes>
      </Properties>
    </Machine>
  </Machines>
</Inventory>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Schema>2018</Schema>
  <Machines>
    <Machine>
      <Price>120000</Price>
      <Properties>
        <Axes>XYZ</Axes>
      </Properties>
    </Machine>
  </Machines>
</Inventory>
```

What tweaks are required to the XSLT to fix this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `xsl:copy` it will copy the node and it's namespaces. If you want to generate an element with the same `local-name()` and drop the namespace, then you need to create a new element. You can create a template to match all elements and generate a generic (no-namespace) element, and then have the regular identity template only match attributes, text(), comment() and processing-instruction() nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cd="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine.DataContracts" exclude-result-prefixes="cd">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd:ArrayOfMachine">
    <Inventory>
      <Schema>2018</Schema>
      <Machines>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </Machines>
    </Inventory>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```